# Unable to copy file "xxx.mdf" in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a project in visual studio 2010 with a database in sql 2008 R2..

I convert this project with crystal report . But when i want run this project this errors happened .

```
Error   13  Unable to copy file "XXX.mdf" to "bin\x86\Release\XX.mdf". The process cannot access the file 'XX.mdf' because it is being used by another process



Error   25  Unable to copy file "C:\madrase\madrase\entekhab_vahed\entekhab_vahed_log.ldf" to "bin\x86\Release\entekhab_vahed_log.ldf". The process cannot access the file 'C:\madrase\madrase\entekhab_vahed\entekhab_vahed_log.ldf' because it is being used by another process.

Error   12  Could not copy "C:\madrase\madrase\entekhab_vahed\entekhab_vahed.mdf" to "bin\x86\Release\entekhab_vahed.mdf". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  entekhab_vahed
```

i don't know how fix it .

Comment: try restarting your sql server service.

Comment: how i can restart my sql server service ?

Comment: press windows-r and type there services.msc and search there SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) and then restart that.

Comment: not work ... errors happended again :(

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your database is not open by Visual Studio. If so Disconnect it using Server Explorer in Visual Studio.
2. Make sure you close the client. There must be no active client using your project
3. If it still happens, try to run Visual Studio "As Administrator"

[SQL Server .mdf file being used by another process](http://forums.asp.net/t/1769128.aspx?SQL%20Server%20mdf%20file%20being%20used%20by%20another%20process%20)

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this by the date, but his is my answer for future searches:

Normally the error will tell you the PID of the process who is using the file, you can end the process, but is not recommended, maybe there is other things using him.

This is happening because you didn't close the connection after the end of your code.

Always use

```
try 
{
    //do your thing
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //close connection
}
```

Try to use

```
using(...context) 
{
    //do your thing
}
```

With this the connection will be closed at the end of stack.

You can implement an IDisposable too or add "Connect Timeout=10" to your connection string.